# How to do get and set values in Ruby Hashes of a given nested key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried something like this with vine gem but not working. Is there any other smart way
Note i do not want to use complex Hash Class like we have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012203/replace-and-access-values-in-nested-hash-json-by-path-in-ruby)

```
require 'vine'
require 'json'

json = '{
   "name":"John",
   "address":{
      "street":"street 1",
      "country":"country1"
   },
   "phone_numbers":[
      {
         "type":"mobile",
         "number":"234234"
      },
      {
         "type":"fixed",
         "number":"2342323423"
      }
   ]
}'
```

h = JSON.parse(json)

```
{"name"=>"John", "address"=>{"street"=>"street 1", "country"=>"country1"}, "phone_numbers"=>[{"type"=>"mobile", "number"=>"234234"}, {"type"=>"fixed", "number"=>"2342323423"}]}
```

a = h.access("phone_numbers.0.type")

```
mobile
```

b = h.set("phone_numbers.0.type", "tablet")

```
{"name"=>"John", "address"=>{"street"=>"street 1", "country"=>"country1"}, "phone_numbers"=>{0=>{:type=>"tablet"}}}
```

expected result is

```
{"name"=>"John", "address"=>{"street"=>"street 1", "country"=>"country1"}, "phone_numbers"=>[{"type"=>"tablet", "number"=>"234234"}, {"type"=>"fixed", "number"=>"2342323423"}]}
```

It is not working for array, or i am missing something
Thanks

Comment: Access `h['phone_numbers'][0]['type']`

Comment: Set `h['phone_numbers'][0]['type'] = 'tablet'`

Comment: Another way of access `h.dig('phone_numbers', 0, 'type')`

Comment: i am interested in get and set, the way i get and the same i should be able to set. I do not need hard-coded way of setting h['phone_numbers'][0]['type'] = 'tablet' . My json will be dynamic it will change every time and user will just provide value like "phone_numbers.0.type". So for any other say if the user provide the hierarchy it should be able to set also

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
require 'json'

#considering that the json is same as you mentioned in the question

h = JSON.parse(json)

# For accessing name 
p h['name']
#for changing the name 
h['name'] = 'ABC'

# for getting address
p h['address']['street']
# for setting address 
h['address']['street'] = "my street"

#get phone number
h['phone_numbers'].each do |ph|
  p ph['type']
  #Set mobile number
  ph['number'] = "123"
end
```

In the above you received a single object in `json`.

But in case if you receive multiple objects, then parse them like below

```
json_array = JSON.parse(json)

json_array.each do |h|
 #All the above steps will remain same
end
```

Comment: this is even more hard coded way of getting the solution. I need solution which is dynamic for any JSON. You can see your code and my code . i just wrote only half a line.

Comment: Your code is not dyamic but mine is , You need to specify `key` each time to read/write

Comment: Shall i use only this much code. json_array = JSON.parse(json)

json_array.each do |h|
 #All the above steps will remain same
end

Comment: it depends on the data  in the `json` variable. If json contains array, then u can use this, but in this method as well, you need to parse the object